# SQL Select Multiple Values StoredProcedure

Tags: c#, sql

I have Two tables : 
Device Details : that have the Details of each Device
other Tables Device Records .

I want to Make Select Statement on List of Devices to Get the Top record for Each from Device Details :

```
SELECT TOP 1
       [t].[DeviceNumber]
     , [d].[CarNumber] AS [CarNumber]
     , [t].TimeStamp
FROM [DeviceRecords] AS [t]
LEFT JOIN [Device_Details] AS [d]
    ON [t].[DeviceNumber] = [d].[AVL_DeviceNumber]
WHERE [t].[DeviceNumber] IN ('013950003919546', '358244017672256', '013950003919876', '013227005026319', '013226001974274') 
ORDER BY
         [t].TimeStamp DESC
```

Instead of doing For Loop in C# and Querying for each Device alone, I was thinking how Could I do it in one time query that returns the TOP record for each device.

Comment: Think you could use a groupby on the devicenumber and select the MAX of the TimeStamp

Answer (score 0):

This is the case when you can use `APPLY`:

```
select t.DeviceNumber, 
       oa.CarNumber, 
       t.TimeStamp
from [DeviceRecords] as t
outer apply(select top 1 CarNumber 
            from [Device_Details] as d 
            where t.DeviceNumber = d.AVL_DeviceNumber 
            order by ... desc) oa   
where t.DeviceNumber in ('013950003919546', '358244017672256',
                         '013950003919876', '013227005026319', '013226001974274')
```

And you should replace `...` with appropriate column from details table.

Comment: This is getting all records for each Device , it must return only One record for each .

Answer (score 0):

Try using a subquery

```
SELECT TOP 1
   [t].[DeviceNumber]
 , [d].[CarNumber] AS [CarNumber]
 , [t].TimeStamp
FROM (Select [i].[DeviceNumber], MAX([i].[TimeStamp]) as 'TimeStamp'
      from [DeviceRecords] AS [i]
      group by [i].[DeviceNumber]) AS [t]
LEFT JOIN AS [d]
    ON [t].[DeviceNumber] = [d].[AVL_DeviceNumber]
WHERE [t].[DeviceNumber] IN ('013950003919546', '358244017672256', '013950003919876', '013227005026319', '013226001974274') 
ORDER BY
         [t].TimeStamp DESC
```